# "wake up" vs "wake back up"

Tags: word-usage

I am informed the typical usage of "wake", that is "wake up"

> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wake)
>
> I woke up with a headache

I guess both of these are correct

> I had a massage yesterday which really helped me to fall asleep. When I **woke up** I felt I was full of energy.
>
> ... When I **woke back up** I felt I was full of energy.

A native speaker told me, the latter sounds more natural, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your native speaker misled you. 
(Native speakers get things wrong all the time!)

To insert **back** is possible but unnecessary and definitely not more natural.

People always wake **again** in the sense that they were awake before they fell asleep. To add **again** is unnecessary. So is to add **up** to **woke**.

So you either just **woke/awoke** or you **woke up** or **woke up again**.

Answer (score 1):

*Back* can be used as an adverb, and it can mean a few things.  One meaning is to emphasize that an action is returning something *back* to a normal state, after being in an alternate state temporarily.

> I put the paper back in the tray (it was temporary out of the tray)

> I got my dog back from the vet (dog was temporarily at the vet)

> I woke back up at 6:00 because someone was banging on my door (you probably fell asleep at 5:30 or otherwise were only sleeping for a short time).